# What does the description option in a cx_Freeze setup script do?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I installed cx_Freeze a while ago, and recently froze my first program. In all the example setup scripts I've seen, the call to `setup()` contains several options, including things such as `version` and `description`. Why does cx_Freeze want a description of my program? What does it do with that information? Most importantly, what am I missing out on if I don't set that argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, cx_Freeze doesn't use the description option, but it's a standard part of setup.py files, which use the same mechanism (distutils) that Python has for distributing packages.

I think the `version` field can be embedded in the executable, though.